# Faraday::SSLError at /callback handshake alert: unrecognized_name

Tags: ruby

I am a total newbie which has started learning Ruby so please be patient with me. 
I am doing Ruby challenges where I need to run a Ruby file that launches a web server on my computer. First I run this application in command line with a command:

ruby app.rb

Then I paste this URL to my browser and access to my local server:

http://localhost:4567

On this local web page I click the link that gets connected to a web server on Internet where I should get authenticated. Till this moment everything works good, but during the authentication I have got an error. If there wasn’t any error during my authorization, the application would retrieve my profile data from the internet server. This is the error that I am getting:

Faraday::SSLError at /callback
handshake alert: unrecognized_name.

I have been trying to resolve this problem for two days. What I have done:

1)  I think this error is connected somehow with Java. I tried to run this application with all versions of Java (6, 7, 8) as people said they had the same problem when they updated to a higher java version. Unfortunately, my version of Ruby doesn’t accept Java 6.

2)  Possible solution which was posted here [SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)), the same as here in 20 similar posts in Stackoverflow about "handshake alert: unrecognized_name" error, where it is suggested to set the jsse.enableSNIExtension property. But I couldn’t understand any of those answers, specifically, where to apply this code. Then I found this link https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-140837 where it was advised to open the Java Control Panel (I did it through System Preferences  Java). I went through the Java tab and clicked View and added “-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false” to the Runtime Parameters and applied it.

3)  Another possible solution was found here [Disable SNI Extension for Ruby net/http - Using IP address with SSL/TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681279/disable-sni-extension-for-ruby-net-http-using-ip-address-with-ssl-tls) (the answer given by ZebGir) but I didn’t find the file *http.rb in my .rvm or even within my whole system.

Please advise any hint or link with the possible solution for my issue.
My system is Mac OS X El Capitan. 
RVM version 1.27.
Java version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the ssl setting for your the faraday library? Something like:

```
connection = Faraday.new 'https://example.com', :ssl => false
```

Also see: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates

Comment: 1) I don't see any faraday library in all my system. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?     2) I've checked the link which you've sent. I tried to change Faraday initializer to include this path as the ca_path variable but my folder /System/Library/OpenSSL/certs is empty. Within /System/Library/OpenSSL there are three directories and one file:  /certs, /misc, /private and file openssl.cnf. I don't know where to put: connection = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://encrypted.google.com', :ssl => {
    :ca_path => "/usr/lib/ssl/certs"
}. What did I misunderstand?